# Errror running Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classnotfoundexception

I am getting error while running all Maven projects in Eclipse as Maven build, but they run successfully if I run manually in Eclipse. Can someone please help.

I have tried running it from Command line.
The same project runs fine when I run from command prompt:
Commands: mvn clean, mvn package, mvn exec:java

Clearly, the problem is with Eclipse. Can someone please help me spot the issue?

Error in Eclipse console:

```
    constituent[0]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/
    constituent[1]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-core-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[2]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-model-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[3]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-settings-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[4]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-settings-builder-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[5]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-builder-support-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[6]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[7]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-artifact-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[8]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-plugin-api-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[9]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-model-builder-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[10]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-provider-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[11]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-api-1.6.3.jar
    constituent[12]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-spi-1.6.3.jar
    constituent[13]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-util-1.6.3.jar
    constituent[14]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar
    constituent[15]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-io-2.6.jar
    constituent[16]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.5.jar
    constituent[17]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/guice-4.2.2-no_aop.jar
    constituent[18]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar
    constituent[19]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar
    constituent[20]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
    constituent[21]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
    constituent[22]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-embedder-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[23]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
    constituent[24]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-sec-dispatcher-2.0.jar
    constituent[25]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-cipher-2.0.jar
    constituent[26]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-cli-1.4.jar
    constituent[27]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-compat-3.8.4.jar
    constituent[28]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/wagon-provider-api-3.4.3.jar
    constituent[29]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.5.jar
    constituent[30]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/aether-connector-okhttp-0.17.8.jar
    constituent[31]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/okhttp-3.14.1.jar
    constituent[32]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/okio-1.17.3.jar
    constituent[33]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-impl-1.6.3.jar
    constituent[34]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.3.jar
    constituent[35]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.3.jar
    constituent[36]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/wagon-file-3.4.3.jar
    constituent[37]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/jansi-2.4.0.jar
    constituent[38]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.1.20211008-0657/
    constituent[39]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.1.20211008-0657/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar
    constituent[40]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/eclipse/jee-2022-06/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/1319/0/.cp/
    constituent[41]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/eclipse/jee-2022-06/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/879/0/.cp/
    constituent[42]: file:/C:/Users/Dell/eclipse/jee-2022-06/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/30/0/.cp/

Exception in thread "main":

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3512)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3516)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2169)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2080)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4012)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4035)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5013)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5020)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.hasAnnotations(Annotations.java:274)
        at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.isBindingAnnotation(Annotations.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.Key.ensureIsBindingAnnotation(Key.java:349)
        at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:336)
        at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:219)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ParameterKeys.<clinit>(ParameterKeys.java:28)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.DependencyAnalyzer.<init>(DependencyAnalyzer.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.<init>(ElementAnalyzer.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:74)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:344)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:651)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutureFailureAccess
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 76 more
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pwskills</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenProj1</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>

  <name>MavenProj1</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>          
 </dependencies>
 
  
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        
        <!-- Executing maven as java program-->
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>JDBCSELECTAPP</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>in.pwskills.JdbcSelectApp</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>   
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

### Build path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="target/generated-sources/annotations">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="m2e-apt" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="ignore_optional_problems" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="m2e-apt" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Please share more information. Which version of Eclipse, Which Version of Maven, which JDK etc. also if you already found out that the problem is related to Eclipse ? Also would it be helpful to post the error as part of the question instead of linking outside...

Comment: @khmarbaise Eclipse Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Maven plugin version in elcipse: 3.8.4
Maven version installed on pc:  3.9.5
JDK version used in Eclipse: 1.8

Comment: [Please describe your problem in a way so that others can reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why do you use an outdated version of Eclipse? Can you reproduce it in the current version? You did what exactly? Why are there two logs?

Comment: Share the pom file and also the build path from Eclipse.

Comment: updated @alex ...

Comment: @howlger: If I run the code in Eclipse by clicking on the run play button in Eclipse, it runs fine, however, if I right click on the project and then go to Run As-> Maven build, then this error shows up..... Also if I use command promt and go the project home directory and then run the maven command, mvn package or mvn exec:java, then also the code runs fine...

Comment: You might want to try uninstalling m2e and installing it again (or updatimg Eclipse and the relevant plugins)

Comment: Eclipse 2022-06 is 5 releases behind. Please do not waste any more time and update now. Support the open source software you use by not asking questions about outdated versions, but about the latest version only. Improve your question instead of adding comments to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating eclipse to current version, the issue got resolved.
Current Eclipse version updated: 2023-09